# Email Markup feature request: automatically accept Gmail schemas between Google Apps for Work accounts

Tags: google-schemas

According to the [Google Developers's Email Markup page about registering with Google](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/registering-with-google), it is possible to test the schema by sending an email to yourself:

> All schemas you send to yourself (from x@gmail.com to x@gmail.com) will be displayed in Google products.

As an admin of a Google Apps for Work domain, it would be great to let users inside my domain to use Gmail schemas.

The idea would be to whitelist all emails within a Google Apps for Work domain, as long as the user sends its emails via an authenticated SMTP connection. This way you ensure that you have a trusted sender (plus the fact that we have DKIM and SPF have already been setup).

This should probably something that can activated via the admin console (at admin.google.com).

I hope this request makes sense. Maybe this is already possible but there is nothing I could find about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@maximd This is possible. Simply fill out this [registration form](https://docs.google.com/a/google.com/forms/d/1PA-vjjk3yJF7MLPOVKbIz3MBfhyma2obS8NIZ0JYx8I/viewform?pli=1). When filling out the form, make sure to specify that your domain is a "Google Apps" domain and you'd like the domain to be whitelisted.

Comment: I just filled the registration form!